# Macintosh say text to speech: new voices cannot accept phoneme codes?

Tags: macos, speech-synthesis, phonetics

there are several great new voices in the Mac text-to-speech tools. With the older voices, like Ralph, you can specify phonemic input like so:

say -v Ralph [[inpt PHON]]dIHv1EHlAXpAXr

(This says "developer".)

However, the new voices don't seem to work. if you try this with Ava (say -v Ava [[inpt PHON]]dIHv1EHlAXpAXr), she reads out the list of letters and numbers as though it's just a string. Does anyone know if it's possible to get at the fine details of the new voices?

Thanks!